# skyrim werewolf/vampirelord hybrid

Tags: skyrim-dawnguard

is it possible to have a werewolf/vampire lord hybrid using console commands or just normal glitches? I have wondered for a long time on the internet and have come out with no answer to this matter. there has to be a way to do this by just normal gameplay. I also have no access to mods and there are no websites I know to get free mods so an answer would be loved.

Answer (score 0):

"*Unless you'r using a mod it's not possible*" is the answer from the link below

You can get links to the mods and more info [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:252346)

Curse look to have free Skyrim mods. Their site is [here](http://www.curse.com/mods/skyrim)